# Why can't I combine font sub properties?

Tags: css

In CSS, you can combine sub-properties. For instance I can define a border like this:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #555;
```

Or I can use a single declaration for the `border` property as a shorthand:

```
border: solid 1px #555;
```

This also works for `background` and other properties. However, it doesn't seem to work for `font`. Say I have this:

```
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
```

If I shorten it to the following, no style at all is applied.

```
font: bold italic;
```

Why is that?

Comment: Border work exactly like font ... suppose you have `border-width: 1px;
border-color: #555;`, you cannot write `border:1px #555`. It won't work because you are missing the border-style. Exactly the same as for font, you are missing font-size and font-family. So you can combine the sub-properties if you concisder *all* of them not only the ones you want

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer on the following page:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/

"You need to supply at least font-size and font-family for the shorthand to work, otherwise it'll just be a syntax error and do nothing."

Comment: Thanks - although this explains how to work around it, I would really love to know why this is different from other properties.

Comment: @Gigi this is how it was defined .. all the properties are different and it's a matter of choice but since it's well defined in the Specification it doesn't really matter. You simply need to follow the rules.

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have any reference that states what these rules are?

Comment: @Gigi the official specification where all the CSS is defined and the only reliable source: https://www.w3.org/TR/ (all the other are simple tutorial website or community wiki)

Answer (score -1):

We can this is called short hand

please check MDN document or font https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

```
font: italic small-caps bold 16px/2 cursive;
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question